# Set Linux file share permissions and ownership on a large NAS quickly

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, nas, nfs

I have an isolated cluster of Linux systems, Windows systems, and appliances all mounting a set of remote shares (via NFS and CIFS). The OS sharing out the filesystems is Linux. I frequently create new remote shares which also get shared out. I have a specific set of requirements for file permissions and ownership that I am currently accomplishing with the following commands (in a little bash script):

```
find -type d -exec chmod u=rwx {} \;
find -type d -exec chmod go=rx {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod u=rw {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod go=r {} \;
find . -exec chown nobody {} \;
find . -exec chgrp nogroup {} \;
find -name ".*" -exec chown nobody {} \;
find -name ".*" -exec chgrp nogroup {} \;
```

This takes forever on a large filesystem. I'm looking for a way to accomplish this significantly faster.

Specifically:

1. All files and directories (including hidden '.' files and
   directories) need to be owned by 'nobody'
2. All files and directories(including hidden '.' files and 
   directories) need to be group 'nogroup'
3. All files need 'rw' rights for the owner and 'r' rights for
   group and other
4. All directories need 'rwx' rights for the owner and
   'rx' rights for group and other

Answer (score 1):

Both `chown` and `chmod` offer a `-R` option that makes the recursive.  These two commands do nearly all of what you want and are quite fast:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX *
chown -R nobody:nogroup *
```

The mode `u=rwX` sets the user mode to read and write and, on the condition that the file/directory already has execute permission for someone, eXecute.  Thus, this keeps execute permission on directories but does not promote other files to execute unless they already had that attribute.  `go=rX` gives group and other read permission and, on the same condition, execute permission.

The command `chown -R nobody:nogroup *` will change owner to nobody and group to nogroup for all files recursively.

These commands work on hidden files in all of the directories recursed through.  The glob `*` does not pick up the hidden files within the current directory.  This can be remedied either by (1) specifying them explicitly, or (2) setting bash's `dotglob` option: `shopt -s dotglob`.

#### Removing execute permission

If you have normal files which need to have their execute permission removed, here is a speedup for that:

```
find -type f -executable -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

Because the above ends with `+` instead of `\;`, find will place as many filenames on the `chmod` command line as it can.  This greatly reduces the number of times that a process has to be created to run `chmod`.

Further, the`-executable` option reduces the number of file names processed strictly to those that need the execute permission removed.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the X (versus x) option, I see it now in the manpage. One of the things I'm trying to do though is strip execute permissions from any files that have them. None the less, for user/group setting, using chown does cut that part in half - making my baseline a bit faster.

Comment: @MT. See updated answer for a speed-up for removing execute permissions.

Answer (score 1):

One thing immediately speed up the process by not using -exec in the find but by piping the resulting names to xargs:

```
 find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

The above is only an example, -print0 correctly passes those nasty files with weird filenames and the -0 parameters on the xargs command reads this output correctly.

Anyway the above command string will be invoked repeatly only a chmod after the maximum number of arguments has been supplied by the find command with the last chmod containing the remaining arguments.  By not spawning a chmod for each file you end up saving a lot of time.